# Transporting data from swift to mySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql, swift3, xcode8

I'm having success at passing information into mySQL database, but for the email field in the DB, I'm getting this...

```
Optional(<UITextField: 0x113d271e0; frame = (37 261; 301 30); text = 'the@Emailaddress.com'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x170055660>; layer = <CALayer: 0x170226340>>)
```

Instead of just the email...  How can i just get the email in there?

Comment: Please check the code while saving ..may be you are saving something wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm saving wrong....  in the PHP script, it has a $_REQUEST for the email as follows....

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['userEmail']);

Comment: simply use $_POST['userEmail'] if you are using post request or $_GET['userEmail'] if a get request.

Comment: if this were just PHP, that would work but I'm trying to pass it from Swift 3 in Xcode and the line of code I have to do that is 

let postString = "userEmail=\(userEmail)&userPassword=\(userPassword)"